# phpmyadmin Directory index forbidden by options

Tags: phpmyadmin, permissions

Hi i m struggling to get phpmyadmin to work on Centos 6.9 x86_64. 
I installed phpmyadmin as root, and i constantly get 
Apache 403 Forbidden Error You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ server error . In the httpd error log i get the following error

"Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ "

My question is how could i resolve this problem. 
1) Should i need to create a virtual host in apache ? 
2)Or is it a file permission problem. As i see i have 644 permissions for files in /usr/share/PhpMyAdmin directory, and 655 root:root for the directories. Could this be my problem?

Comment: Please add the relevant apache configuration.

Comment: I use the default one, i only modified the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Comment: Got it working by moving the wordpress directory to /var/www/html, without creating a vhost, accessing it by ipaddress/phpmyadmin.